# Cannot cat file which has space in name in linux

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I believe there's a simple fix but cannot debug it out.

I have file called "`file name with space`"
How do I `cat` this file from Linux bash ?

Comment: `cat "file name with space"`  or  `cat file\ name\ with\ space`

Comment: `cat "file with space"` doesn't work!? Good luck.

Comment: Sure: name your file `file_name_with_underscore`...

Comment: @H2CO3 Why if it works if everythin is implemented well?

Comment: @glglgl Safe, convenient, cross-platform and idiomatic.

Comment: A fourth option would be to change the IFS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does putting quotation marks around the name not work?

```
cat "file name with space"
```

Answer (score 9):

A third option  would be

```
cat 'file name with space'
```

where the file name may contain everything but the `'`.

If it does, such as `file n'ame`, replace every `'` with `'\''`:

```
cat 'file n'\''ame'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the escape character '\' like this

```
cat file\ name\ with\ space
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclosing the file in double quotes should work i.e.

```
cat "file name with space"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have run into this problem on Linux and in Cygwin.  The one thing I found that works is to enclose the name in double-quotes and to replace non-traditional characters with asterisks.  For example:

> **tail File.basename.Job With Spaces.log**

*becomes...*

> **tail "File.basename.Job*With*Spaces.log"**

I tried escaping the spaces with backslashes, whether unprotected, protected with double-quotes, or protected with single-quotes, and in all cases tail parsed the names at the spaces as though unprotected.

Comment: This is **WRONG**.  Three (slightly) different perfectly good (correct) answers have already been given; if you have a problem with them, try again (and make sure you do what they say).  But your answer **will not work!!**

Comment: This **IS** a good answer. When you have filenames in a file and want to cp them in a for loop, you use the backquote and cat the files.(e.g. `for i in `cat bakuplocations`; do cp -u "$i" .; done`) Then, if the filenames have spaces it will not work any of the other suggestions except this one.

Comment: @user890332 No, then you are doing it wrong as it might catch other, slightly differently named files. If you have file names in a file, you do `while read i; do cp -u "$i" .; done < backuplocations`.